# Does WIX support detection of framework 4.6 yet?

Tags: wix

I have WIX version 3.10...

I am updating an installer to require .NET 4.6.  It previously required 4.5.1.  I am using the WIX NetFxExtension to detect the presence or otherwise of the framework.
For framework 4.5, I had this in the XML:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45" />
<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.5.1. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR (NETFRAMEWORK45 AND (NETFRAMEWORK45 >= "#378675"))]]>
</Condition>
```

If I change the '45' to '46' (and set the comparison value to something appropriate for 4.6), WIX does not recognize the property.

Does the WIX NetFxExtension support detection of .NET framework v4.6?  If so, what am I doing wrong?  If not, what else can I do to detect it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use a different property - `WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED`. According to the docs, it is:

> Set to 1 if .NET Framework 4.6 or later is installed.

This property is available starting from v3.10. See [this article](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html) for details.

Comment: That's Great! Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question.