# LGHT0094 bundling .NET 4.6.1. standalone installer

Tags: wix, wixsharp

I need to create an installation package that includes the .NET 4.6.1. standalone installer. I’ve followed the `\WixSharp\Samples\Bootstrapper\WixBootstrapper_NoUI` sample – it works for the .NET 4.6. standalone installer `NetFx46Redist`:

```
var bootstrapper =
        new Bundle("My Product Suite",
            new PackageGroupRef("NetFx46Redist"),
            new MsiPackage(productMsi)
            {
              Id = "MyProductPackageId",
              DisplayInternalUI = true
            });
```

However, when using the .NET 4.6.1. package group id `NetFx461Redist`, I’m getting the following error:

```
BootstrapperBundle.wxs
Windows Installer XML Toolset Linker version 3.10.3.3007
Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.
C:\WixSharp\Samples\Bootstrapper\WixBootstrapper_NoUI\BootstrapperBundle.wxs(13) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'ChainPackageGroup:NetFx461Redist' in section 'Bundle:My Product Suite'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank You,

Palo

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394318/does-wix-support-detection-of-framework-4-6-yet). Supposedly there is a property you need to set within 3.10 that will enable it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net 4.6.1 is not supported in the current stable release of WiX v3.10.3, but is available in WiX v3.11.0.906 weekly release.